# Azure Virtual Machine DELETE API returning HTTP 204 instead of 404

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am using the following API:
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/delete**

When **trying to delete a VM which does not exist**, I am given this response:

**Response Code: 204**

Headers-
cache-control: no-cache
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
x-ms-correlation-request-id: 0bda7be7-6f2a-4202-9565-04d16c210606
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-deletes: 14996
x-ms-request-id: 0bda7be7-6f2a-4202-9565-04d16c210606
x-ms-routing-request-id: WESTINDIA:20181223T044056Z:0bda7be7-6f2a-4202-9565-04d16c210606

Body: null

**Shouldn't ideally a HTTP 404 be returned?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Track asynchronous Azure operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations) to better understand the flow of execution when using **Azure**'s management APIs.

As far as I understand, you are getting a **204** because the operation doesn't complete immediately. If you want to check the operation's state and end result, you need to query for it using methods described in the above link.

**Update**

After trying the operation on one of my subscriptions,  looking at portal's activity log, it seems that the operation is being logged as "Succeeded". I'm afraid that the only way to know if a VM exists or not, is by trying to query for its info.

I also think, that in previous versions of the API a 404 was being returned in case the VM was not found, but for some reason it was changed (maybe because if it is not found then it already in a "deleted state").

Hope it helps!

Comment: In case of asynchronous Azure operations, an URL is provided in the headers on which a GET call can be done to get the status of the operation. No such URL was provided in response for my case. It seems, 201 and 202 are returned when the operation is not completed immediately. 200 and 204 are returned after successful completion.